# Описать класс для работы с двумерными массивами чисел. Реализовать возможность выполнения комбинаторные операций присваивания(+=, -=)

Tags: c#, массивы, ооп, классы, перегрузка-операторов

Не получается перегрузка операторов для двумерных массивов

```
class cameraman
{
    int[,] A;
    static int n;
    Random rnd = new Random();
```

Конструктор

```
public cameraman(int size)
    {
        n = size;
        A = new int[size, size];
    }
```

Метод заполнения массива случайными числами

```
public void ArrayInt_RandomIn(int max)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                A[i, j] = rnd.Next(max + 1);
    }
```

Метод вывода массива

```
public void ArrayInt_Out()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                Console.Write(a[i, j].ToString() + "\t");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Перегрузка оператора

```
public static cameraman operator + (cameraman cameraman1, cameraman cameraman2) {
        cameraman c = new cameraman(n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                int inc = cameraman1.A[i,j] + cameraman2.A[i,j];
                c.A[i, j] = inc;
            }
        return c;
    }
```

Что я собственно делаю в программе:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        cameraman m = new cameraman(3);
        cameraman x = new cameraman(3);
        cameraman d = new cameraman(3);
        m.ArrayInt_RandomIn(100); x.ArrayInt_RandomIn(50);
        m.ArrayInt_Out(); Console.WriteLine("\n"); x.ArrayInt_Out();
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        d = m + x;
        Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Следует учитывать, что при перегрузке не должны изменяться те объекты, которые передаются в оператор через параметры. И в документации сказано, что с перегрузкой + будет работать и +=.

Что нужно исправить, чтоб выводилось 3 массива: 2 массива и 3й - сумма элементов 2х массивов?

Answer (score 0):

так вы фигурные скобки в циклах ваших расставьте правильно

```
    public void ArrayInt_Out()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                Console.Write(A[i, j].ToString() + "\t");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В программе
Вместо

```
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

Написать

```
d.ArrayInt_Out();
```